# Comment traduire "Journals and Logs" ?

Tags: traduction

Il faut que je traduire "[name] journals and logs- you can do them on the go!"

Je n'ai aucune idée comment traduire "logs!" Le dictionnaire dit qu’ils sont les deux "journaux."

Comment est-ce que je peux mieux traduire cette phrase ? Merci et remercie 100x !

Comment: Je peux te confirmer que journal est bien la traduction appropriée pour log. Si on veut tout particulièrement parler des logs informatique des log files donc on dira "fichier journal".

Comment: Pour l'anglais "journal", s'il s'agit d'une suite d'évènements, on peut parler de "fil de l'eau"

Comment: Merci aCOSwt.
C'est pour le site web d'un thérapeute. Il parle de ses clients "logs and journals"

Comment: Ha! Alors pour le "journal" il s'agit donc de "*health journal*" ? En français il s'agit du "*carnet de santé*"

Comment: Ce n'est pas un health journal. 
A la fin du chaque jour il faut qu’un client écrire un journal dans lequel il document leurs sentiments.

Comment: Je viens de parler avec mon boss beaucoup et il m'a dit que les logs and journals sont les memes choses x.x

Answer (score 1):

Je traduirais simplement par « compte-rendu » ou peut-être plus spécifiquement par « compte-rendu d'états d'âme » et encore par « compte-rendu d'analyste ».

Il s'agit d'un concept connu de peu de monde, il n'y a pas de terme assez courant et il faut en définir un.

Comment: Je vois, il s'agirait de deux unités distinctes selon vous et la première constituerait une archive d'évènements (log); selon ce point de vue, qui semble plus juste, carnet convient assez bien.

Comment: @jus cogens prime Il ne peut pas s'agir de « journal intime »; cette sorte d'écrit est limitée à une exposition de sentiments personnels à un psychologue (thérapeute); voyez les commentaires ci-dessus, ils sont encore présents. Un compte rendu est une sorte de rapport et oui, bien sûr, on peut faire un rapport sur un rapport, mais il ne s'agit pas de cela, comme vous devriez le comprendre après avoir lu les commentaires.

Comment: Merci, j'avais bien lu les commentaires. En fait j'essayais de réfléchir à votre affirmation « il s'agirait de deux unités distinctes selon vous et la première constituerait une archive d'évènements (log) ». Un thérapeute peut aisément demander à un patient de rédiger un journal intime mais là n'est pas la question, et on aurait possiblement utilisé d'autres termes en anglais que ceux présentés etc. Peut-être que la personne qui demande va présenter éventuellement d'autres éclaircissements. Merci !

Comment: @jus cogens prime Je ne crois pas que l'on doive détailler ses sentiments dans un journal intime et on peut parler des sentiments des autres et de leur vie aussi; ce n'est pas ce qui intéresse en premier lieu ce psychologue; il est fait état dans les commentaires seulement de "documenter" les sentiments personnels.